# how to replace tags in MsWord doc files using php

Tags: php, ms-word, doc

I have a doc file in which I have some text and formating and in different part of the doc file I have some TAGS (eg. IDS, LABELS, TOTAL, etc.).

Is it possible possible to replace those tags with appropriate text using PHP?
Is there a php class to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is http://phpword.codeplex.com/, you would be interested in `templating` feature.